# Click button and toggle the button label

Tags: javascript, apex, visualforce, salesforce-lightning

I have created following function.

```
function appendActionToMarkertText(markerText, lat, lng) {

     markerText = markerText + '<br/> <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral" id="GRadiusID" onclick="GenerateRadius(' + lat + ',' + lng + ')"> Generate Radius </button>';
     return markerText;
 }
```

I want to take this button id (GRadiusID) to outside for my jQuery part.

```
j$(document).ready(function () {
    j$("#GRadiusID").click(function(){
    var gr = j$(this).text();
    if(gr=="Generate Radius"){
        GenerateRadius(lat, lng);
     }
     else if(gr=="Clear Radius"){
         clearRadius();
     }
     });
  });
```

Comment: Don't use picture for your code please. If someone wants to try it, he firstly need to write it by himself.

Comment: @klediooo ok.. I changed it to code.

Comment: what the problem ?

Comment: Since your tags include Salesforce references I suggest you take a look at their training materials for Lightning Web Components: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lightning-web-components-basics?trail_id=lex_dev. Their approach is a bit different that what you have here. There are a couple issues with the code samples, but honestly I would expect SF related components to be different enough that addressing those issues is unlikely to get the results you want.

Comment: @laguf1.mobi inside the function have a button know. I want to take that button id to outside for my jQuery code. If have any path to do that?

Comment: Thank you @acrosman . I will refer that trailhead too.

Answer (score 0):

you can only map the node after you insert it into the DOM. So the solution for you to do that is that as soon as you call the `appendActionToMarkertText` function, you will use jquery to find the button. Example:

```js
$(function(){
function appendActionToMarkertText(markerText, lat, lng) {

     return markerText + '<br/> <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral" id="GRadiusID" data-lat="'+lat+'" data-lng="'+lng + '"> Generate Radius </button>';
 }
 
 $('#btn').click(function(){
    $('#example').html(appendActionToMarkertText('make text', 'aaa', 'bbb'));
    
    $("#GRadiusID").click(function(){
      var gr = $(this).text().trim();
      if(gr=="Generate Radius"){
        alert($(this).data('lat'));
        //GenerateRadius(lat, lng);
      }else if(gr=="Clear Radius"){
         clearRadius();
      }
    });
 })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="example">hello word</div>

<button id="btn">click me</button>
```